# JavaScript confirm with ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, confirm

I am using JavaScript confirm in an ASP.NET program, the confirm window works when I want it to, however I am not sure how to retrieve whether the user clicks 'OK' or 'Cancel'.

This is in the site master:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">

                    var confirmMsg = document.getElementById('MainContent_confirmMessageHidden');

                    if (confirmMsg != null) confirm(confirmMsg.value);

            </script>
```

This is in the aspx.cs file:

```
    private void Confirm(string msg)
    {
        //Response.Write("<script language = 'javascript'>window.alert('" + msg + "')</script>");
        confirmMessageHidden.Value = msg;
        confirmMessageHidden.Visible = true;


    }
```

How can I retrieve the choice of the user?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use return value of javascript confirm function. For example,

```
...

if (confirmMsg != null) {
  var answer = confirm(confirmMsg.value);
  if (answer) {
    alert('OK Clicked');
  }
  else {
    alert('Cancel Clicked');
  }
}
...
```

Choose appropriate action instead of alerts as per the functionality needed by you.

EDIT:

A sample code to prevent navigation using confirm

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doConfirm() {
       var confirmMsg = document.getElementById('MainContent_confirmMessageHidden');
       if (confirmMsg != null) {
          return confirm(confirmMsg.value);
       }
       return true;
    }
</script>

<a href="link to some other page" onclick="return DoConfirm();" />

<input type="sumbit" value="Click Me" onclick="return DoConfirm();" />
```

Comment: ok this works, how could i tell it to proceed if OK is clicked? (proceed being going to where the page was directed before the confirmation)

Comment: @Karl, if your script is invoked on submit button then you need to return true (on confirmation) on click event handler to proceed and return false to do nothing. The same will apply to a hyperlink (anchor element). See my edit.

Comment: when i try doing that, i create a function in the sitemaster but it simply doesnt do the confirm alert at all

Comment: but the problem is this is not a normal button, its a select button which is autogenerated, so im not sure how i can access its onClick

Comment: @Karl, what do you mean by select button? Do you mean a drop-down that does auto-postback (onchange will be correct event handler).

Comment: sorry i didnt explain well, i have a gridview with a select button on the left of each row, which opens each row into a group of records,(its not normal, its blue and underlined, like a hyperlink)

Comment: @Karl, selection button in nothing but anchor link. You can use `OnClientClick` property of select button from markup to link up on click javascript handler.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a conditional action based on confirm choose:

for example something like

```
if (confirm(confirmMsg.value))
{
     document.location('<your_process_page_url.aspx>?confirm=1');
}
else
{
     document.location('<your_process_page_url.aspx>?confirm=0');
}
```

Then in process page you can retrieve the choose by

```
<%
 var choose = Request.QueryString["confirm"];
%>
```